# Class hierarchy using instancetype vs id

Tags: objective-c

I have a simple class hierarchy with my constructors using `instancetype` instead of `id` as the return type. If I wanted to forward to the super class's constructor, I get this warning:

> Returning a Vehicle * from a method returning Car *: interface Vehicle is not a successor of Car

If I switch from `instancetype` to `id`, of course, the error goes away since there's less type strictness. What is the recommended way of doing this?

**`Vehicle.h`**

```
@interface Vehicle 

- (instancetype)initWithIdentifier:(NSString *)anIdentifier

@end
```

**`Vehicle.m`**

```
@implementation Vehicle

- (instancetype)initWithIdentifier:(NSString *)anIdentifier {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        // do a bunch of stuff to construct the object
    }

    return self;    
}

@end
```

**`Car.h`**

```
@interface Car : Vehicle 

- (instancetype)initWithCarID:(NSString *)aCarId

@end
```

**`Car.m`**

```
@implementation Car

- (instancetype)initWithCarID:(NSString *)aCarId {
    // I want to forward the call to the parent and preserve the 
    // two different constructor signatures

    // The following line produces this warning:
    // Returning Vehicle * from a method returning Car *: interface Vehicle is not a successor of Car
    return [super initWithVehicleIdentifier:aCarId];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `-init*` methods, this is `instancetype` is unneeded. The compiler will automatically treat `id` as `instancetype`.

Try it yourself, see what warning get produced from the following code:

```
[[[NSArray alloc] init] length];
[[[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:nil] length];
```

See NSHipster's writeup of [`instancetype`](http://nshipster.com/instancetype/) for more details.

---

**update**

As a rule, `instancetype` is useful for any method which returns an instance of itself. `-init*` is just a exception to this rule because of a naming convention rule.

Objective-C is like English grammar: every rule has an exception.

Comment: So instancetype is necessary only for class constructors?

Comment: The methods with implied related result types are `+alloc`, `+new`, `-init`, `-retain`, `-autorelease`, and `-self`, @Will. More details [in the Clang docs](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#related-result-types).

Comment: @JoshCaswell - I'm going to risk suggesting the OP has found a compiler bug. Why should stating something explicitly fail just because it is implicitly assumed? `instancetype` states the return type is the type of the receiver. In `Car`'s `initWithCarID:` the type of the receiver in `[super initWithVehicleIdentifier:aCarId]`, being `self`, is surely (to the best of the compiler's knowledge) `Car *`. This is why the common statement `self = [super init...]` is accepted without issues - the types match due to related result types. Of course I might be missing something...

Comment: Yeah, you know, that looked funny to me, too, @CRD, but I didn't actually think about it until now. I think you may be right.

Comment: @JefferyThomas - Given Josh's response I suggest you submit a bug report to Apple. While unnecessary, what you did should really have worked.

Comment: @JoshCaswell - Just because I can't put two @'s in a comment!

Answer (score 1):

I would use "id" since its the usual way to implement such things - see Apple example code, etc. If you really want to use `instancetype` then go with Leo's answer.

The reason you are getting the warning is because an instance of "Vehicle" (what you are returning) is not exactly an instance of "Car". It will work but you have told the compiler that the method will return an instance of "Car".
See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16743494/instancetype-vs-class-name-for-singleton) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
@implementation Car
- (instancetype)initWithCarID:(NSString *)aCarId {

    self = [super initWithVehicleIdentifier:aCarId];
    return self;
}
```

Or, simply cast the returned object:

```
- (instancetype)initWithCarID:(NSString *)aCarId {
    return (Car*)[super initWithVehicleIdentifier:aCarId];
}
```