# Definite class name in a singleton method

Tags: objective-c, design-patterns, singleton

Here is a sample code of a singleton method:

```
+ (id)sharedManager {
    static MyManager *sharedMyManager = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedMyManager = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedMyManager;
}
```

Is there a way to get rid of the certain class name declaration `MyManager *` and replace it with some abstract type like `self *` or `instancetype`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `id` within the method, to avoid referencing the actual class name, and then specify an `instancetype` return type so that the compiler knows that what is being returned is an instance of this particular class:

```
+ (instancetype)sharedManager {
    static id sharedMyManager = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedMyManager = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedMyManager;
}
```

---

A word of warning: By implementing it this way, you can be lulled into a false sense of security that this class can now successfully be subclassed.

But this actually has problems. But if you have two different subclasses of this class, you now only have a single shared singleton (unless you override `sharedManager` in both of the subclasses).

For example, let's imagine you had two subclasses of this class, `SubClass1` and `SubClass2`:

```
SubClass1 *shared1 = [SubClass1 sharedManager];
SubClass2 *shared2 = [SubClass2 sharedManager];

NSLog(@"%@", shared1);
NSLog(@"%@", shared2);
```

In this case, `shared2` will not return an instance of `Subclass2`, because the `static` of `sharedMyManager` will be of the first subclass for which you called `sharedManager`. Thus `shared2` will confusingly return that previous instance that was instantiated by `[SubClass1 sharedManager]`.

For this reason, some people suggest that you avoid this `instancetype`/`id` pattern, because it suggests a degree of safe subclassing which really can cause problems in these sorts of curious edge-cases. Because of this, many will argue that you should reference the actual class names within `sharedManager`.

As a practical matter, I confess that I still use this `instancetype`/`id` pattern in a code snippet to facilitate easy creation of singletons, but just be aware of this limitation.

Comment: @Eugene - No worries. By the way, please note my caveat on this pattern in my revised answer.

Comment: I see. Guessing this is exactly that place where we, obj-c developers, need to have Class Variables.